# Ubuntu 20.10 desktop-icons gnome-shell extension crashing

Tags: 20.10, desktop-icons

I just updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10, and I see the following repeating error from the desktop-icons gnome-shell extension in /var/log/syslog...

```
Nov 25 12:55:00 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[106347]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a90494e220 ==
Nov 25 12:55:00 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[106347]: #0   7ffe0555f410 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:574 (1bb2727a4060 @ 25)
Nov 25 12:55:00 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[106347]: #1   55a90c9f9128 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:212 (362843806ab0 @ 85)
Nov 25 12:55:00 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[106347]: #2   55a90c9f90a0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:148 (362843806bf0 @ 12)
Nov 25 12:55:00 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[106347]: #3   55a90c9f9018 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:251 (1bb2727bed30 @ 12)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix these crashes?

Comment: you use wayland session?

Comment: @nobody Nope, no wayland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano (gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons) with the following https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/...

> [image]